# EventHandler JFXTextField

Tags: java, javafx

Tengo una duda mas, Yo en mi proyecto lo tengo separado por carpetas de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una carpeta (Main) para la clase main con el metodo `start(Stage stage)` y el metodo `main(String [] args)`
Otra carpeta (Model) para la logica de negocio
Otra para las Vistas (View) que va a tener la aplicacion
y por ultimo otra (ViewModel) para el Controlador de cada Vista.

Codigo del SampleController:

public class SampleController {

```
@FXML
private JFXTextField TxtWatts;

@FXML
public void initialize() {

    TxtWatts.setOnKeyTyped(event -> SoloNumerosEnteros(event));
}

public void SoloNumerosEnteros(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    try{
        char key = keyEvent.getCharacter().charAt(0);
        if(!Character.isDigit(key))
            keyEvent.consume();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo tienes todo para poder aplicar el `EventHandler` a tu campo de texto. Solo necesitas agregar al controlador un método `initialize()` anotado con `@FXML` y dentro de este el código correspondiente al manejo del evento.

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
     TxtWatts.setOnKeyTyped(event -> SoloNumerosEnteros(event));
}
```

Es importante aclarar que el código que hemos escrito dentro del método `initialize()` no debemos agregarlo en el constructor de la clase, ya que se lanzaría un `NullPointerException`. Esto se debe a que cuando se ejecuta el constructor, todos estos atributos son nulos. Por el contrario, el método `initialize()`, se ejecuta después que se hayan inyectado los atributos anotados con `@FXML` (ej. @FXML private JFXTextField TxtWatts).

**EDITADO:**
Por algún motivo que desconozco el código anterior no funciona en Java 9, quizás se trate de algún bug (mi versión es 9.0.1). Si trabajas con esta versión de Java utiliza el siguiente código en vez del anterior.

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
     TxtWatts.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, event -> SoloNumerosEnteros(event));
}
```

Comment: Disculpa te joda nuevamente pero... al introducir es codigo en mi proyecto El codigo es: `@FXML
    public void initialize() {
        TxtWatts.setOnKeyTyped(event -> SoloNumerosEnteros(event));
    }` cuando ejecuto la aplicacion no filtra los numeros, deja pasar cualquier tipo de input. Aparece a un costado Overrides method in favafx.event.EventHandler Capaz sea ese el problema pero ni siquiera se que significa y no encuentro nungun tipo de informacion

Comment: ¿Tu controlador implementa la interfaz `Initializable`?

Comment: No no la implementa. Y marca eso. Tambien intente implementarla para probar pero aparece exactamente lo mismo: Overrides method in favafx.event.EventHandler

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues el código integro de tu controlador, porque yo acabo de agregar tú código a una aplicación mía y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta. Parece que se trata de un bug de Java 9.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)